# How to overcome 'Run-time error 430' from XP to another XP computer?

Tags: com, vb6

I've been getting very frustrated by this :

> Run-Time error '430' Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

I know there are a lot of people with this problem but there is always a Windows 7 in the middle.

I have an old VB6 code I have inherited (gasp) and I installed Visual Studio 6 to recompile this thing on my XP SP3 machine. On this machine it works like a charm.

When I try the app on another XP computer (which is as updated as the compiling machine) I get that darn error. I've really tried the works to get this to disappear but with no success. I know VB6 is outdated and not supported anymore but there has to be something!

Tried on many XP machines and none works. They all get the error. Does Visual Studio install some kind of run-time which is making it work on my computer?

Sorry if I am so verbose. Any help is welcome.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280383/what-could-cause-vb6-run-time-error-430) helps.

Comment: It doesn't help to whinge on and on about VB6 being old, you just aren't using it properly.  This sounds like a broken compatibility issue as described in the other topic linked by Jay.  Hire a VB6 programmer if you have to.

Comment: This can even be easier than broken compatibilty - you just don't have required components on another computers. VS installs alot of components; you need to include all referenced ones (look at project references and components) with your installer.

Comment: +1 @Arvo Sounds like the installer may not be installing all the components, or maybe not the correct version of some components. You *have* actually run an installer on these other machines, right?

Comment: @Jay, I did read and digested that article. I tried the 'Package & deployment wizard' with no success. I'm not whining VB being old, I'm just the new guy who gets what nobody wants. Been a C++ programmer for a decade now and I'm really puzzled by this VB problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is awkward. My bad as usual... The application I was running opened ok, but when I clicked on a button I got the '430' error. Turns out it is caused by an OCX which is probably loaded at that point. I put the OCX next to my exe file and now it's working.